# Issue with ArrayList copy the data

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class to calculate numbers, for example the class creates an arrayList [2,3,4], then i pass this list to another class called Variable which has a method called tomaloya(ArrayList with numbers). When a list of numbers is passed to this method the numbers are not added to the list in Variable class. Anyone can help me?

---

```
import java.util.*;
public class Variable {

    public String id;
    public String idcorrecto;
    public String tipo;
    public int tamanio;
    public int posicion;
    public boolean resultado;
    public List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Variable(String t1,String t2,String t3,int tt1,int p1,boolean r1,ArrayList<String> listt){
        id = t1;
        idcorrecto = t2;
        tipo = t3;
        tamanio = tt1;
        posicion = p1;
        resultado = r1;
        lista = listt; //ESTA LISTA ES PARA LAS TRIDIMENSIONALES...            
    }

    public void tomaloya (ArrayList<String> toma){
        System.out.println(toma);

        lista.addAll(toma);
    }

    public     String getTipo(){
        return tipo;
    }     

    public     int getPosicion(){
        return posicion;
    }

    public     boolean getResultado(){
        return resultado;
    }

    public     String getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public     String getIdcorrecto(){
        return idcorrecto;
    }

    public     int getTamanio(){
        return tamanio;
    }

    public  String getLista(int elemento){        
        return lista.get(elemento);
    }

    public  void addLista(String elemento){            
         lista.add(elemento);           
    }    
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code how you're passing the list to the method tomaloya ?

Comment: Yes, most likely the `toma` list is empty

Comment: Hi! Can you please provide the code where you populate arrayList and pass it to your tomayola method.

Comment: the list contains the numbers [2,3] and i call the method with v1.tomaloya(List)

Comment: Provide us exact code, please

Comment: change lista.addAll(toma); to this.lista.addAll(toma);

Comment: You should reduce the visibility of your instance variables, i.e. make them `private` instead of `public`.

Comment: Show us the code where you create `v1` and call tomaloya. You say the other list contains numbers but the list in `Variable` contains String objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this keyword before all the class properties. for eg. 
this.lista.addAll(toma);